# Percent of Total Windowed in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have these two tables:

A data table...

```
ImaginaryData = 
DATATABLE (
    "Fruit", STRING,
    "Colour", STRING, 
    "Amount", INTEGER, 
    { 
        { "Apple", "Red", 10 }, 
        { "Apple", "Green", 5 },
        { "Pear", "Pink", 100 },
        { "Pear", "Blue", 65 },
        { "Orange", "Black", 12 },
        { "Orange", "White", 8 }
    } )
```

A lookup table...

```
ImaginaryLookup = 
DATATABLE (
    "Fruit", STRING, 
    { 
        { "Apple" }, 
        { "Pear" },
        { "Orange" }
    } )
```

Then I created this simple 1-to-many relationship:

[image]

Now I am trying to create a Percent of Total measure to add to a table - but I want the percent of total to be based on the total of the fruits that are selected in a slicer of ImaginaryLookup:

This is what I have tried:

```
 %Total = 
DIVIDE(
    sum( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
    CALCULATE(
        sum( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
        ALL(ImaginaryData)
    )
)
```

If all fruits are selected in the slicer then it works fine as I'd expect:

[image]

But if I select say "Orange" then the results are not what I want, as I'd like the 12 and the 8 to be a percentage of 20:

[image]

This also does not give me what I want:

```
%Total = 
DIVIDE(
    sum( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
    CALCULATE(
        sum( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
        ALLEXCEPT(ImaginaryData, ImaginaryData[Fruit])
    )
)
```

Because now if I select say Pears and Oranges then it is giving me the percent as a percent of each fruits total, rather than the percent of 185:

[image]

---

note to Alexis

If I try this:

```
%Total = 
DIVIDE(
    sum( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
    CALCULATE(
        sum( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
        ALLSELECTED( ImaginaryData[Fruit])
    )
)
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ALL` function removes all filter context. Try it with `ALLSELECTED` instead. That will preserve your slicer selection while removing the table visual's filter context.

If you use this (note I didn't specify a column):

```
%Total = 
    DIVIDE(
        SUM( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
        CALCULATE(
            SUM( ImaginaryData[Amount] ),
            ALLSELECTED( ImaginaryData )
        )
    )
```

Then you should get this result:

[image: % Total Measure]

The reason it doesn't work if you do `ALLSELECTED(ImaginaryData[Fruit])` is that the `Colour` filter context still exists, so you don't pick up the other fruits because those are all different colors than the row you are evaluating on.

Comment: cheers Alexis - if I swap out ALLEXCEPT or ALL for ALLSELECTED then it just returns 100% on all rows

Comment: I think I may have to issue a correction here. If the slicer is on the lookup table, then using ALL (or similar functions) on the data table does not remove the filtering on the lookup table (because it's upstream in the relationship diagram). Try applying ALLSELECTED to the lookup table instead or just simply ALLSELECTED() with no table argument.

Answer (score 1):

I used following measure and it works as expected:

```
%Total = 
CALCULATE(DIVIDE(sum(ImaginaryData[Amount]),
CALCULATE(SUM(ImaginaryData[Amount]),ALLSELECTED(ImaginaryData))))
```

Comment: your function is basically the same as that of Alexis?

Comment: I used addional CALCULATE at the beginning. I'm new to DAX so I'm not 100% how it affects the calculations, but when I tried different filters I get results that you wanted in original question.