# DAX in Power BI - How to add a measure to calculate the percentage

Tags: powerbi

I have a visual that contains Filings for each CourtHouse. I am trying to create a measure to add as a column that gives the percentages for each courthouse as a percentage of the total. I am using # of filings from the Filings Table and courthouse from Node levels table.

Does anyone have the DAX to add this measure. Thanks

enter image description here[enter image [description][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXuN6.png) here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT5vH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRdor.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Percent of Total Windowed in Power BI DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393069/percent-of-total-windowed-in-power-bi-dax)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
Total% = divide(sum(# of Filings), Calculate(sum (# of Filings), All(Filings)))
```